# ASP.NET MVC - Set different entry point to Web Aplication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am developing an ASP.Net MVC Website which the expected routing behavior is like Facebook

When user is not logged in and access the site he is showed the welcome page under
`www.domain.com/`

If he logs in we want him to access the website content still in 
`www.domain.com/`

How should i define the routes?

Edit:  To clarify more as instructed

I want to serve a different Index action if a user is logged in and a different if he is not.

An approach that doesn't work

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View();
}

[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Index()
{
 return View();
}
```

So with two different Index Actions the default Route

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

will perform as i want.

Comment: You don't need to define the routes; this is a controller issue. The route would be the same.  You're looking for an [Authorized] attribute or looking to use `IPrincipal` and do some workflow based off of it. http://addisagile.wordpress.com/2012/12/09/custom-authentication-in-asp-net-mvc-4/

Comment: I know about [Authorized] and IPrincipal. The problem code like this is not valid
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
            return View();
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }


What i need different Index Actions based on if a user is logged in

Comment: That code should go into your question. Seems like you haven't given us enough to help you.

Comment: You can't have two controller actions named the same thing. You're going to have to just allow everyone to hit that controller action and then do processing inside the controller action to kick everyone who isn't authorized out -- or you'll need to make your own custom authorization attribute that derives from `AuthorizeAttribute` and have it redirect people who aren't logged in to "You're not logged in" experience.

Comment: What I would do is use of Session...When user Logs In create a Session.Like Session["sessionname"]=userName; then If(Session["sessionname"]==null){ return RedirectToActoin("yourAction")} else Return Your Desired Action

Comment: @GeorgeStocker  We wish to keep the Url Behavior like Facebook.
This means if you are not logged in `http://www.domain.com/` shows the welcome page. If you hit `http://www.domain.com/` while you are logged in it should show your wall

Comment: @janina If we redirect we will end up in a page like `http://www.domain.com/Controller/Action` which is not our expected behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking in the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) i found out i can pass the name of the View i want in the constructor.For the sake of completeness here is my implementation.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Welcome");
        }
    }
```